# Compensation for a Missed Connection Flight

Tags: compensation, ec261

I had missed my connecting flight from Warsaw (WAW) to Belgrade (BEG) due to a delay of an hour approximately on my first flight from London (LHR) to Warsaw. As a result, I had to wait three hours in the queue at the airport in Warsaw, where they offered me to stay one night in a hotel and then fly to Austria and then to Serbia the next morning. In other words, my final destination was reached three or more hours later than planned due to the missed connecting flight.

My first question is, according to EU Regulation (EC) No. 261/2004, how much am I entitled to receive in compensation? From what I have checked so far, it is €400 and I would like to confirm that.

Also, I have contacted the airline directly via email providing them with my e-tickets. Do I need to add anything else? I would prefer not to use any legal websites that would represent me for a fee.